# returning all columns from mysql

Tags: phpmyadmin

```
SELECT * FROM `order_lines` WHERE `order_id` = 28563
```

phpmyadmin 4.7.2 [cpanel system so I can't install the latest]

server side mysql returns all columns

firefox returns all columns

chrome returns 5 columns

browsing the table crahses in chrome

Notice in ./libraries/DisplayResults.php#1227
 Undefined offset: 5

Backtrace

> ./libraries/DisplayResults.php#1346:
>   PMA\libraries\DisplayResults->_getTableHeadersForColumns( array,
>   array, array, array, array, boolean false, string 'SELECT * FROM
>   `order_lines` ', ) ./libraries/DisplayResults.php#4450:
>   PMA\libraries\DisplayResults->_getTableHeaders( array, array, string
>   'SELECT * FROM `order_lines` ', array, array, array, boolean false, )
>   [much more traceback]

rebooting the server didn't do anything [it seems to be client side only if 1 browser works and 1 fails]

It's not all tables, but I've had it randomly on a few tables.

Comment: find any solution?